# Regex match everything except string provided

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am having troubles understanding how to use regex so that it will match everything but a string provided. I've tried using the negate operand `?!` such as `(?!red|green|blue)` however that does not seem to work either.

Say I have a string that looks like this:

```
red blue green purple
```

and I want to negative match on `green` so that my resulting match would be:

```
red blue purple
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: Just replace `" green"` with an empty string.

Comment: Well the idea was that i was going to replace everything that matched with an empty string, so that all I would be left with is `green`.

Comment: You should explain what you are doing, what the environment is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track with `(?! ... )`, but you have to keep in mind that this is a negative *lookahead*, not just a negation operator.  That means it verifies that the text after the current position does **not** match the pattern in your lookahead, and if so, it fails the match at that position.  It does **not** match anything in and of itself.  You still have to build a pattern around it.  Here is an example of how you could write such a pattern:

```
(^| )(?!green)[^ ]*
```

- `(^| )` Beginning of string **OR** literal space character
- `(?!green)` Assert that the next characters in the string do not match "green"
- `[^ ]*` Match everything up to the next space.  We can safely do this because the lookahead will have already failed the match if it was "green".

Input string:

```
red blue green purple
```

Matches:

```
red blue purple
```

Note: Looking at how you've been testing the patterns on regex101, I will point out that this pattern will match each space-delimited item as separate matches.  It is not possible to match a non-continuous string in regular expressions, so this is the closest solution you will get.  If you need a singular non-continuous match, you are going to need to either rework your program or use something other than regex.

Answer (score 2):

A simple method to achieve this would be to use look arounds.

Like this: `.+(?=green)|(?<=green).+`

Test regex here: https://regex101.com/r/T8ULn0/1

```
.+(?=green)   match everything that precedes 'green'
|             OR
(?<=green).+  match everything that follows 'green'
```

Here is JS code:

```js
let s = "red blue green purple"
let pattern = /.+(?=green)|(?<=green).+/gm
console.log(s.match(pattern))
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than *not* matching on green, you could match on green and replace it out.

For instance in PostGres:

```
select regexp_replace('red blue green purple','(green)','','g');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add what to capture as well, the regex you're looking for is this one it seems

`^(?!red|green|blue)([a-z0-9]+)$`

Comment: I just tried this and it doesn't yield any matches. https://regex101.com/r/b2GDQq/1